# Change background color of label onClick via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox, onclick

I am making a **checklist**. I am adding the **checkboxes** dynamically via javascript and adding labels for them too. 
Now I want **when I check a checkbox the background color of the label to change indicating the item has been selected** but onClick attribute is not allowed in *"label"* tag.
So I added the text as a child of checkbox but it is not visible but the onclick event is working on checkbox.

```
var chked = document.createElement("input");
            chked.type = 'checkbox';
            chked.value = data[friendIndex].id;
            chked.id = friendIndex;
            chked.width = '300';
            chked.onclick =  function (){document.getElementById(this.id).style.backgroundColor='#4285f4';};
            var label = document.createElement('label');
            label.htmlFor = friendIndex;
            label.id = friendIndex;
            label.setAttribute('onclick' ,function (){document.getElementById(this.id).style.backgroundColor='#4285f4';});
            label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[friendIndex].name));
            chked.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[friendIndex].name));
            var mybr=document.createElement('br'); 
            chklstTarget.appendChild(chked);
            chklstTarget.appendChild(label);
            chklstTarget.appendChild(mybr);
```

Comment: rendered html format?? r u covering input with label or bot are sepereate?

Comment: yes rendered in html<br>i am covering input by label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any reason you need to do this via Javascript? You can do this using CSS only.

### HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" />
<label>Check Me!</label>
```

### CSS:

```
input[type=checkbox] + label {
    color: black;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    background: red;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/LLxQG/)

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery click function to toggle the class

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
        $(this).parent().toggleClass("checked");
    });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/eNeyeLo/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

How about append CheckBox to Label.
Then you can get CheckBox's onClick event from click ChkeckBox and Label area both.
And change label's color.

example)

```
label.appendChild( chked );
label.appendChild( textToDisplay );
chklstTarget.appendChild( label );
```